# How to create a simple bar chart using javascript

Tags: javascript

The user will input the data for the graph.  I have used a drawline, but I cant get the location right. Here is my code so far. I cant use a bar chart libary, due to java enviroment being embeded into a webpage.

```
// Ex5-1: Weather Data Graph
enter code herevar canvas;
canvas = openGraphics();
var sun;
var n;
var xposition;
xposition = 40;
sun = prompt("enter the sun");
sun = parseInt(sun, 10);
 ///xposition= xposition +10;
canvas.drawLine(40, 10, 40, 245);
canvas.drawLine(40, 245, 390, 245);
canvas.drawString("225 ", 10, 30);
canvas.drawString("180 ", 10, 70);
canvas.drawString("135 ", 10, 110);
canvas.drawString("90 ", 10, 150);
canvas.drawString("45 ", 10, 190);
canvas.drawString("0 ", 10, 230);
canvas.drawString("J ", 50, 250);
canvas.drawString("F ", 80, 250);
canvas.drawString("M ", 110, 250);
canvas.drawString("A ", 140, 250);
canvas.drawString("M ", 170, 250);
canvas.drawString("J ", 200, 250);
canvas.drawString("J ", 230, 250);
canvas.drawString("A ", 260, 250);
canvas.drawString("S ", 290, 250);
canvas.drawString("O ", 320, 250);
canvas.drawString("N ", 350, 250);
canvas.drawString("D ", 380, 250);
canvas.setStroke(30);
canvas.drawLine(xposition, 230, xposition, sun);
canvas.paint();
```

Comment: Java environment in the browser? Javascript has nothing to do with java? Or did  you mean you have a java applet embedded in the web page? You can always look at  http://d3js.org/ which is a handy javascript library for visualisations.

Comment: Agree with Stefan. You can even look to https://developers.google.com/chart/

Comment: It would help if we had access to drawString and drawLine

Comment: You are asking a Java question, not a JavaScript question. See [this](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/applet/CircleLine.shtml) for more information about the code you are trying to use. Read  Wikipedia's [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) and [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java) pages and browse [this SO page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java) to understand the difference between Java and JavaScript. Just because Java is running in a browser does not make it JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry I can't use any libraries like jqplot, as I am creating the bar chart on a webpage which is Java-embedded, if that makes sense (hard to explain for me lol). I need to create a weather bar chart according to sunshine hours which have been given to me by my teacher, and then plot these sunshine hours for each month of the year on a bar chart (e.g. 30 hours for January on the chart, etc). I can only use whatever Javascript base code (I think it's JavaScript, it says this in the module guide provided) is available, so cannot bring any external libaries into the web page, just raw JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are writing this javascript bar chart plotter as an exercise, I would use [jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php).

Comment: Sorry I can't use any libraries like jqplot, as I am creating the bar chart on a webpage which is Java-embedded, if that makes sense (hard to explain for me lol). I need to create a weather bar chart according to sunshine hours which have been given to me by my teacher, and then plot these sunshine hours for each month of the year on a bar chart (e.g. 30 hours for January on the chart, etc). I can only use whatever Javascript base code (I think it's JavaScript, it says this in the module guide provided) is available, so cannot bring any external libaries into the web page, just raw JavaScript.